# GIT: <Directory> already exists in the index

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Hi I have an existing checked in directory which contains a lot of common code.

I moved the code to an external repository and then tried to use it as a sub-module.

The issue now is that when i try to add the sub-module, an error is thrown:  already exists. I tried multiple forums and couldn't find any resolution.

I have already removed the original directory from the repository and then checked in the changes(removal of directory). Still the issue. some how it saying that the directory exists in the index.

how to deal with this??

Comment: Did you do a git rm to "move" it?

Comment: i have a windows to did a shift delete from the original repo...should i try git rm first..?

Comment: tried git rm also...didnt work at all/..same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When removing a directory or file from git, you have to explicitly instruct git that you are deleting it, otherwise git keeps tracking it internally. You do this by using

- `git rm -r --cached directory`
- `git commit -m "removing directory"`

The `-r` is used becuase it is a directory so we need to remove recursively, the `--cached` is used to keep the local copy in tact (otherwise it would be deleted).

Now, in your case, you have alrady moved and created a submodule out of the directory. So, you need to

- move the directory out once again (becuase it is a git repository in itself now)

  ```
  mv directory ../
  ```
- Remove the directory and commit

  ```
  git rm -r --cached directory && git commit -m "removing directory"
  ```